# Usage "on" or "about" in "Some observations on/about..."

Tags: grammar

The complete sentence is "Some observations on metamorphoses of French lyric opera". It is intended to be the title of an article. 
Which preposition -- "on" or "about" -- should I use after "observations"?

Incidentally, should I use the definite article in this context? Which phrase is correct:
1. Some observations on/about the metamorphoses of French lyric opera.
2. Some observations on/about metamorphoses of the French lyric opera.
3. Some observations on/about the metamorphoses of the French lyric opera.
4. Some observations on/about metamorphoses of French lyric opera.

Comment: There is a mistake: a missing *the* determiner.

Answer (score 0):

Although there's nothing wrong with *about*, *on* is more typical. To some extent, it's a matter of style.

Whether or not to use the definite article with *metamorphoses* is a matter of what you mean. If you are referring to *all* of the metamorphoses that pertain to French lyric opera, then use *the*, because you are specifically defining the group of metamorphoses that you're referring to. If you are talking about *some* of them, then you have an indefinite group, and you may leave out the word *some* if you wish.

I wouldn't use *the* with *French lyric opera* unless you are only referring to one of them, for example *Gluck composed the French lyric opera Iphigénie en Aulide*. *Opera* functions as an uncountable noun, and adding "French lyric" to it just means it's an uncountable subset of the uncountable noun. On the other hand, you would use *the* if you said *the French lyric operas*, because now you're referring to all of the individual operas of that particular style. You can count those.

Comment: on is more formal, in writing.

Answer (score 0):

For your title:

> Some observations on metamorphoses of French lyric opera

To answer your question, I would choose **on** instead of **about**. **About** is more general than **on**. For example:

- I wrote a book on French Lyric Operas.

Implies that you're discussing specific operas.

- I wrote a book about French Lyric Opera.

The book is more general in nature about the topic and doesn't necessarily discuss specific operas.

---

Here are some other alternatives:

> Observations on Metamorphoses of French Lyric Opera**s**

I think **Some** is implied because you're never going to be able to name all of them in your paper. But **Operas** needs to be plural.

> Observations of Metamorphoses in French Lyric Opera[s]

Just a different take. **Opera** can be singular or plural. You could also use "of" instead of "in" but that would be too many "of"s in the title.

> Metamorphoses in French Lyric Opera[s]

More concise. Not sure if by eliminating **Observations** you're losing any implied meaning. A singular **Opera** means Opera in general. A plural **Operas** suggests that specific operas are discussed.